# How can I find where main()'s return address is sitting in the stack?

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, exploit

I need to do a remote a buffer overflow exploit for a class. I understand MOST of it. It involves overwriting main's return address so I can execute my own code. 
But we never covered how to find the location of the return address in memory...
I keep getting it wrong and the exploit isn't working :(

I'm sitting in gdb and I have my buffer's address (0xbffff3dc)

Now, I need to find out where in the stack the return address is sitting (so I can find out the offset between it and my buffer).

Then I'll know how much space I have to add:

- a NOP (0x90) "sled"
- my shellcode
- more NOPs ???
- the address for my buffer (overwriting the return address)
- "\r\n" ???

^ I'm not sure whether the things marked "???" are completely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [objdump](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html).

just try `objdump -d your-executable` and it will give you assembly code as well as addresses

Comment: This is useful for the addresses of the code, but not the location where the return address of main is stored on the stack.

Here's what I've found out with GDB:

- 1st var in main@ 0xbffff384
- arglist @ 0xbffff798
- argv  @ 0xbffff834
- locals @ 0xbffff798
- prev frame @ 0xbffff7a0
- EBP  =  0xbffff798
- EIP  =  0xbffff79c

The return pointer should sit right before EBP right?

Comment: Just an alternative run `gdb` and `disas function`. Can specify which function you want to disas